# WiFi gets disconnected after some time in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers

I'm new to Ubuntu (and any kind of linux distributions). Now, I'm using `Ubuntu 14.04` and Windows 7 (dual boot) in my `HP Notebook 15-r203tx.`

The problem is that, connection to the internet using WiFi gets disconnected after some time. And, there is no such problems in Windows.

I'm not sure about the way Ubuntu works with the hardware drivers. I installed all the required drivers (related to network) in Windows and it is working fine. But, I did not install any drivers for Ubuntu (as I already said, I don't know the way Ubuntu works with hardware and its drivers).

What could be the reason for the issue? Do I need to install any drivers for Ubuntu?

Thanks in advance. It'll be a great help.

**Edit:**

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

```
0a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2231]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Edited my post.